# Sublime Text 3 - "scroll_past_beginning"

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

"scroll_past_end" can scroll until the last line at the top.

I want to scroll until the first line at the bottom.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is a feature request for this functionality [here](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1270). It doesn't have any activity though. It is not currently possible.